# Difference between jniLibs.srcDirs and jni.srcDirs

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have seen these two commands for adding custom directory as your jni folder. But what's the difference between these two.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jni.srcDirs = ["libs"]
    }
}
```

and

```
sourceSets {
     main {
         jniLibs.srcDirs = ["libs"]
     }
}
```

Some please clear me.

Comment: `jni` would contain source code of native libraries (or at least the instructions for finding it), while `jniLibs` would contain the results, both intermediate stages and final `.so` output.

Comment: Ok so .cpp / .h / .cc files are put inside jni folder.

Comment: Yes that is correct. It is not necessary to build the jni files every time since .so files are already created once. If you are putting `jni.srcDirs = []` like this then automatic  Android NDK build will be disabled.